# MySQl Connector; TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

Tags: jupyter-notebook, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I am trying to connect to mysql in python using jupyter notebook. Here is the code for the connection (password excluded for obvious reasons):

```
vg = mysql.connector.connect(
    port = 3306,
    user = 'root',
    passwd = '****',
    database = 'video_game',
    host = '127.0.0.1',
    allow_local_infile = '1'
)
print(vg)
myc = vg.cursor()
```

And here is the error it throws:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_17004/821559105.py in <module>
----> 1 vg = mysql.connector.connect(port = 3306,user = 'root',passwd = '****',database = 'video_game',host = '127.0.0.1',allow_local_infile = '1')
      2 print(vg)
      3 myc = vg.cursor()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\pooling.py in connect(*args, **kwargs)
    291 
    292     def get_connection(self):
--> 293         """Get a connection from the pool
    294 
    295         This method returns an PooledMySQLConnection instance which

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py in __init__(self, **kwargs)
    118         try:
    119             self._cmysql.autocommit(value)
--> 120             self._autocommit = value
    121         except MySQLInterfaceError as exc:
    122             raise errors.get_mysql_exception(msg=exc.msg, errno=exc.errno,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\abstracts.py in connect(self, **kwargs)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py in _open_connection(self)
    289             # No row available
    290             return None
--> 291 
    292     def next_result(self):
    293         """Reads the next result"""

TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

I have seen other posts on Stack Overflow where this error is because the port is in quotes but I have fixed that and am still getting the same error. I have even tried all of the variables without the quotes just in case and no luck.

Here are the only other lines in my notebook at the moment just in case there is somehow an issue with them causing this:

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install mysql-connector
```

```
import os
import mysql.connector
```

Comment: Stab in the dark, try changing `allow_local_infile = '1'` to `allow_local_infile = 1`.